# iOS Swift AVPlayer: NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12643?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am trying to display `.m3u8` contents with `AVPlayer`.

It works when videos are <5 minutes long.

It causes error in `KVO` observer when videos are ≈1 hour long.

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String: AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
{
    guard context == &playerViewControllerKVOContext else
    {
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
        return
    }

    if keyPath == "player.currentItem.status"
    {
        var newStatus = AVPlayerItemStatus.Unknown

        if let newStatusAsNumber = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? NSNumber
        {
            newStatus = AVPlayerItemStatus(rawValue: newStatusAsNumber.integerValue)!
        }

        if newStatus == .Failed
        {
            // We are here when video is ≈1 hour long.
            print("\(avplayer.currentItem?.error)") // avplayer is an instance of AVPlayer
        }
    }
}
```

I get following error text:

> Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The
>   operation could not be completed"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000065f980 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12643 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12643),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed})

`AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800` is an [Unknown Error](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/averror.code/1390250-unknown).

Underlying error is `NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12643`.

I can't find any description of `-12643` error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an example URL?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Wowza streaming service is used: `<client.domain>/vod/smil:episode_ccbf8a2b-30db-0e21-680d-8fce98755cdc.smil/playlist.m3u8` Sorry, but my client doesn't let me specify the domain. Please take a look at [.m3u8 file](https://yadi.sk/d/pa5NgvsLyykhz) which causes the `-12643` error.

Comment: I can't play that m3u8 file without knowing the domain, can I?